# Call yourself God

Tags: word-request

Is there a word for calling or considering  yourself a deity?

There was a king of Shinar called Nimrod, who called himself a deity according to certain Islamic scholars and made people worship himself. Nimrod  was in the age of prophet Ibrahim(Abraham). This great prophet and a friend of Allah, also known as the patriarch of all subsequent prophets, died at the age of one hundred and seventy five years.

Comment: You might try "made himself a god". The "regular" way to say this. Caligula made himself a god.

Comment: How heavy is your emphasis on the idea that it's the person who is styling himself a god as opposed to a person whom other people style as a god?

Comment: There is an old joke about the braniac who told God he had figured out how man was created.  He knew about how soil worked, and minerals, water and all.  And he knew anatomy.  So comes the showdown.  He tells God he is going to demonstrate, and reaches down for a scoop of dirt to start with.  But God stopped him, saying "Use your own dirt!"

Answer (score 33):

Yes, there is such a word in English. It's called *deification* whereby a human being is made into and worshiped as a god. This was a common practice among many ancient nations.

Example #1:

> He **deified** himself to make people worship him as a god.

Example #2:

> The Romans **deified** their emperors making them equal to gods.

---

Another very similar word in meaning to *deify* would be *idolize*.

Example:

> He was **idolized** by his tribe and revered as a god.

Comment: To be clear, "to deify" is to make some person or thing into a god.  For example, the Roman emperors were often *deified* after their deaths.

Comment: @Andrew but he used to force people to worship himself when he was alive

Comment: @Arman my history is a bit fuzzy, so you may be right.  In that case these emperors were deified while they were still alive.  Either way, same verb.

Comment: He self-deified himself??

Comment: *Deified* is right, but *self-deified* is an awkward and rare construction. A single word that covers this idea may not be possible.

Comment: *Self-deification* is used with some regularity, with [almost 15,000 examples in Google Books results](https://www.google.com/search?q=self-deification&oq=self-deification&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l2.6829j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22self-deification%22&safe=active&tbm=bks); for some reason, the verb form is not nearly as popular—there are only 82 hits in Google Books.

Comment: I like [apotheosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apotheosis), personally.

Comment: almost defecation

Comment: @1006a “Almost 15,000” sounds high until you consider that *deification* has almost 300,000 hits. That makes *self-deification* 5% of what *deification* has—and *deification* isn’t that common a word.

Comment: @KRyan Yes, it's not a common topic of conversation generally. But to me, 15,000 examples takes it out of the realm of "so awkward it's unidiomatic" and into "inelegant, but people use and understand it in those rare instances when it's needed" territory.

Comment: @JAB Apotheosis implies *actual* godhead, and refers to the process more than the result.

Answer (score 9):

The best term for this is *self-styled god* or *self-proclaimed god*. Using *deify* with a reflexive pronoun, like *he deified himself*, could also work.

#### *Self-styled* or *self-proclaimed*

English has a lot of terms for someone who names himself something: *self-styled*, *self-declared*, *self-proclaimed*, and so on. Many of these have their origins in medieval titles, or *styles*, so a *self-styled king* would be someone who is not recognized as king by any country, but refers to himself as king and tries to insist on royal honorifics (*your majesty* and so on).

However, these terms are generic and can apply to any title or honor—including divinity. A *self-styled god* or *self-proclaimed god* would be the same as a *self-styled king*, but for divinity rather than royalty.

#### *Deify*—but not *self-deify*

To *deify* is to make something into a god. It could be used to refer to the actor him-or-herself, as in *he deified himself.*

The construction *self-deify* is understandable, but awkward and basically unheard of—see this graph of [usage of *deify* vs. *self-deify*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=deify%2C%22self-deify%22&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdeify%3B%2Cc0), where *deify* enjoys some usage, but *self-deify* is literally not found at all. So *self-deify* could be English, but not idiomatic English.

A similar word is *apotheosis*, which means to become a god. *Self-apotheosis*, though, doesn’t really make much sense, and *apotheosis* is less well-known anyway. It’s also more positive—the term usually refers to someone who actually does become a god (it’s from Greek; that sort of thing happens in Greek myths). *Deify* instead refers more to someone who is worshiped as a god.

Comment: English allows for things like self-deify but there would have to be a really good reason for using it.

Answer (score 4):

It could be called a 'god complex', or 'delusional', 'messiah complex' but it depends on whether or not the person *is* a god. Followers of many religions would say that their god knew s/he was a god and was not delusional. 'Delusions of grandeur', might also be appropriate.

There is the problem that in using these words that some people might be offended. If you spoke this way about any recognised-by-many deity, you could find yourself in trouble.

In fiction, if you are making up a 'new' god, you'd probably be okay. In a group of agnostics, you would be fine with any of the terms I suggested, though they are negative. If you want an positive way to say 'delusional', I'm stumped.

Comment: Unknowingly imaginative?  ;)

Answer (score 3):

I think Cookie Monster's answer is the most accurate here. But I found another word that might be helpful. It's [divinize(verb)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/divinize) or [divinization(noun)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/divinization) . And I think this [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apotheosis) article might be useful for your research.

Comment: In my somewhat long life, I have never seen divinize.

Comment: Just because it is in the dictionary, doesn't make it usable. If you are learning a language or even improving your skills, it's best to avoid arcane terms.

Comment: @Lambie and of course Im here learning the language. I think everyone does.

Comment: Well, I am not here learning the language. I am here to give people what I know.

Comment: @Lambie Okay, you are an expert, you dont have to learn :)

Comment: It''s not about being an expert. It's just about being reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

There are ***self-deification*** and ***self-divinization*** (both are also spelt without the hyphen). However, these words are usually used in a more figurative, anthropocentric manner, rather than considering oneself literally a god.

Answer (score 0):

**Apotheosis** is a noun describing the process of elevating something to the status of deity.  The verb form is **apotheosize**.

Comment: apotheosis is not related to making oneself a god at all.

Comment: "a·poth·e·o·sis
əˌpäTHēˈōsəs/
noun
the highest point in the development of something; culmination or climax.
"his appearance as Hamlet was the apotheosis of his career"
**the elevation of someone to divine status; deification**." from Google dictionary. The 'oneself' part is missing.